# ASP.net SiginManager and Hashed Passwords

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently developing an API which needs to be secured. The security should include a hash and salt values.

My preference is to use the existing pipeline in .net core 2.0, which contains the following in SignInManager:

```
public virtual Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure);
```

In all of the examples I have located, the password is sent to the controller in clear text, which is not acceptable.

I can hash the password, and then submit to the SignInManager, but it will not authenticate due to the default hashing already in place.

A quick look at the aspnet.aspusers table clearly shows hashed passwords, which will have been previously created manually, based on clear text as defined in the call to `services.Configure<IdentityOptions> Password` class.

So, this seems like an infinite loop as to how to resolve the problem. I assume that there is a custom interface which can be provided, but given the sketchy details in the docs, I am not locating this.

How do I tie all of this together in a coherent solution?